# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property "success" of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, properties, typeerror

So, I'm getting an error within my if/else statuement part of my code where it returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined. Any Ideas?

```
function responseReceivedHandler(data) {
/* Successful request:
  {
     "success": true,
     "todos": [ '...', '...', ... ]
  }

  Unsuccessful request:
  {
     "success": false,
     "error": "..."
  } */

/* Your solution goes here */
if (this.response.success === true)
{
console.log(this.response.todos);
}
else {
console.log(this.response.error);
}
}

$.get("https://wp.zybooks.com/todos.php", { day: "Monday" }, 
responseReceivedHandler, "json");
```

Comment: Looks like `this.response` does not exist. I think you might want `data.success` instead.

Comment: @JamesT Thanks that worked!  However, now it's not printing like my list that is set for "todo" it's supposed to be multiple items.  Any idea why it's only pulling the first item and not the rest?

Comment: Not sure, have you tried setting a breakpoint in the handler?